# Can you use Hilt in a Java-only Android project?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

According to the [official integration guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android), you need to add

```
plugins {
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
  ...
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:{hilt_version}"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:{hilt_version}"
}
```

to your `build.grade` file. However, when I do a gralde sync, I get the following error:

> Plugin [id: 'kotlin-kapt'] was not found in any of the following
> sources:

is it possible to use Dagger-Hilt in a pure java project? Or do you have to either use plain Dagger or use Kotlin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following instead of kotlin-kapt:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:{hilt_version}"
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:{hilt_version}'
}


plugins {
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Classic Googlers - they did not mention this in their Hilt guide documentation. They seem to have a talent to ALWAYS omit important notes or info in their docs....

Comment: Just we need to use annotationProcessor instead of kapt. Thanks @Ocasin

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use Hilt in a Java-only Android project.

**Step 1**

Add hilt plugin in module level.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

**Step 2**

Add hilt plugin in app level.

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}
```

**Step 3**

Add the following dependencies and make sure to use annotationProcessor instead of kapt. As kapt is for kotline based projects.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
}
```

And now finally you are able to use hilt in you java based android application.

[image]